# Is there any way to embed a SWF file in my Stack Overflow profile?

Tags: discussion, support, profile-page

I am Android Developer and I want to embed an [URL](http://www.android.com/swf/conveyor.swf) in my [Stack Overflow Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1318946/pratik-butani).

I have following tag but it's not working:

```
<embed src="http://www.android.com/swf/conveyor.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="200%" height="500">
```

Is there any way?

Comment: No idea what being an Android developer has to do with SWFs. I've heard of publishing AIR apps for Android - does a similar conversion exist in the other direction? How does that work?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this kind of embed `*` in any of the texts we edit here. The profile formatting follows the same rules as the rest: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

You can convert it to an animated GIF, that works.

<sup>`*`: not sure about Stack Snippets</sup>

Comment: Thank goodness there isn't.